# Moq VerifySet(Action) strange behaviour

Tags: moq

I use Moq to test some behaviour. I want to verify set view's model property as new instance of Message class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MessageFormPresenterTests
{
    private NameValueCollection queryString;
    private Mock<IDatabase> mockDatabase;
    private Mock<HttpContextBase> mockHttpContext;
    private Mock<HttpRequestBase> mockRequest;
    private Mock<HttpResponseBase> mockResponce;
    private Mock<IMessageFormView> mockView;
    private MessageFormPresenter presenter;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.queryString = new NameValueCollection();
        this.mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
        this.mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        this.mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        this.mockResponce = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        this.mockView = new Mock<IMessageFormView>();

        this.mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(this.mockRequest.Object);
        this.mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Response).Returns(this.mockResponce.Object);

        this.mockRequest.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString).Returns(this.queryString);

        this.presenter = new MessageFormPresenter(this.mockView.Object) { Database = this.mockDatabase.Object, HttpContext = this.mockHttpContext.Object };
    }

    [Test]
    public void ViewLoad_QueryStringNotHasMessageIdParameter_PopulateViewModelAsNewMessage()
    {
        // Act
        this.mockView.Raise(v => v.Load += null, new EventArgs());

        // Assert
        this.mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model = It.Is<Message>(m => m.Id == 0));
    }
}
```

But this test pass even if i not write this functionality in my MessageFormPresenter. When i set breakpoint to action call (v.Model = It.Is(m => m.Id == 0)) and debug my test, Model property returned as "Castle.Proxies.MessageProxy" type and has all properties with default values (value of Id property is 0, of course).

Why is this happening? I don't setup anything to return and Moq should return null by default.

P.S. Excuse me for my poor english. I hope you understand what i'm talking about)

UPDATE1: MessageFormPresenter class:

```
    public class MessageFormPresenter : Presenter<IMessageFormView>
{
    private IDatabase database;

    public MessageFormPresenter(IMessageFormView view)
        : base(view)
    {
        View.Load += this.View_Load;
    }

    public IDatabase Database
    {
        get { return this.database ?? (this.database = DatabaseFactory.DatabaseInstance); }
        set { this.database = value; }
    }

    private void View_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int messageId;
        var messageParam = Request.QueryString[QueryParamNames.MessageId];

        if (messageParam == null)
        {
            View.Model = new Message();
            return;
        }

        if (!View.IsAdmin)
        {
            Response.Redirect(PageUrls.AccessDenied, true);
            return;
        }

        if (int.TryParse(
            messageParam,
            NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out messageId))
        {
            View.Model = this.Database.Single<Message>(messageId);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(PageUrls.DefaultPage, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Base class `Presenter<IMessageFormView>` provided by WebFormsMvp framework.

UPDATE2: If i use strict behaviour TargetInvocationException will be thrown in base constructor of MessageFormPresenter, even if i setup all properties of `Mock<IMessageFormView>`.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of `MessageFormPresenter`? At least constructor and the `Load` event handler.

Comment: You can also try to use "strict" mock `new Mock<IMessageFormView>(MockBehavior.Strict)`....

Comment: @nemesv is in the right area - the default behavior is MockBehavior.Loose and it will initialise values to default(T) I think.